# Mock output binding Azure function python

Tags: python, unit-testing, azure-functions

I want to create a unit test for my Azure Functions in Python using unittest. I am following the example in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#unit-testing , but I have added a blob output binding to my Http Trigger function, which I do not know how to mock when manually calling my function.

This is my function.json:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ],
      "route" : "normalize"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "name": "todb",
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out",
      "path": "carga-db/web_{rand-guid}.csv",
      "connection": "bbdstorage_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is my TestCase class:

```
import unittest

import azure.functions as func
from web_api import main

class TestFunction(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_my_function(self):
        # Construct a mock HTTP request.
        req = func.HttpRequest(
            method='POST',
            body=None,
            url='/api/normalize')

        # Call the function.
        resp = main(req, #what to put here?)

        # Check the output.
        self.assertEqual(
            resp.get_body(),
            b'Hello Test',
        )
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution here? I'm running into the exact same issue (with a different output binding - though that shouldn't matter) with no solid documentation on the topic?

Comment: No, not really :(

Comment: Same problem here. Documentation just brings the most simple case to light, which is that we only trigger with http request and return http response and nothing else..

Comment: Saw in another stackoverflow that you can use mock from the unittest module to mock the binding like this:
outblob = mock.Mock()
# Call the function.
resp = main(req, outblob)

Answer (score 1):

Just like [Akerblom mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64215034/mock-output-binding-azure-function-python/78030675#comment127733958_64215034), you can use a mock object ([MagicMock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock) ), inject it into your function, and test when and how this mock object is called.

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

import azure.functions as func
from web_api import main

class TestFunction(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_my_function(self):
        # Construct a mock HTTP request.
        req = func.HttpRequest(
            method='POST',
            body=None,
            url='/api/normalize')

        # Create a mock Out object
        mock_out = MagicMock()

        # Call the function.
        resp = main(req, mock_out)

        # Check the output.
        self.assertEqual(
            resp.get_body(),
            b'Hello Test',
        )
        
        # Assert that the mock method was called correctly
        mock_out.set.assert_called_once_with(b'Hello Test')
```